# How to use get UTF-8 accents with ncurses

Tags: c++, utf-8, ncurses

I installed recently the new Windows 10 build 14393 and i wanted to use the new linux subsystem. So i decided to learn ncurses and i cant't find how to have the UTF-8 code of an character with accent like `è` from `getch`.
So here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char ch;

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8");

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();

  printw("èèè\n"); // i can print accents

  ch = getch(); // if i press è it gives me 2 characters
  printw("%d", ch);
  ch = getch();
  printw("%d", ch);

  getch(); // wait for a key to exit
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

For example if i press `è` it gives me 2 characters code which are `-61` and `-88`, so how can i have its code from `UTF-8` table which is `232` ?
I use ncursesw and here is my `g++` command to compile :

```
g++ file.cxx -o file -lncursesw
```

And my locale is configured as fr_FR.UTF-8.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: [long story](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr17/), in short utf8 encodes different code points as sequences of 1 or more bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getch()` call returns 8-bit characters in a 32-bit `chtype` value (`char` will not work well, but is not the problem in this case).  UTF-8 is a **multi**byte encoding, and in this case, ncurses will return the bytes—one per call.

To get a Unicode (wide-character) value, use [`get_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html), e.g.,

```
wchar_t ch;
get_wch(&ch);
```

You should of course check the return-value of `get_wch`, but its return value would be **`OK`** or **`ERR`** — the character is returned via the pointer passed as argument.

Comment: When i compile it says me `get_wch was not declared in this scope`. Do i need to include another header file ?

Comment: Ok i found i had to `#include <ncursesw/cursesw.h>`. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I think you meant `<ncursesw/curses.h>` (the other one is for the C++ binding).

Comment: I'm using C++. ;-)

Comment: I forgot that <ncursesw/cursesw.h> incudes <ncursesw/curses.h>, because the former defines methods which you are not using.  It would work, though...